# Problem migrating nvarchar(max) (MSSQL) to text (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, mariadb, database-migration

I'm in the process of migrating an SQL Server 2012 database (running on Windows Server 2008) to MySQL (MariaDB, running on CentOS 7.6.1810). I'm using MySQL Workbench (installed on the Windows server) to migrate the data. For most tables and columns it works, except for "nvarchar(max)" and "text" data types. MySQL Workbench keeps hanging, despite no locks being active on the data I'm trying to export.

I tried first converting the data to "varbinary(max)", then exporting (to MySQL's equivalent "longblob"), and then converting it to the target data type "longtext". Exporting the data this way works, but the encoding is wrong and I don't know how to fix it. For example:

```
Source (MSSQL, data type nvarchar(max)):
"service"

Source (MSSQL, data type varbinary(max)):
"0x7300650072007600690063006500"

Target (MySQL, data type longblob):
"s e r v i c e "
```

I've tried to subsequently cast / convert this to longtext, text, char(n) etc., also specifying encodings (utf8, utf16, ucs2) but I either end up with "s e r v i c e" or some Chinese characters. I've also tried to convert the source data type to "varchar(max)", "text", but without success (converting it to "text" also leads to MySQL workbench hanging).

The problem specifically applies to columns where some values have a length > 8000 bytes. If all values were smaller I would've just converted all "nvarchar(max)" columns to "nvarchar(n)", which I confirmed worked just fine.

The only two options I personally see are:
- Figure out a way to convert the target binary data to the target database encoding (ucs2), without just removing all the spaces in for example "s e r v i c e ", or
- Figure out a different way to export the data from MSSQL to MySQL, which also supports lengths in excess of 8000 bytes.

Comment: Is it binary data, or text stored as binary data that you need to represent as text again? The `00` padding is a sign you're dealing with UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: Yeah, try to dump as UTF-8, and don't use VARBINARY.

Comment: @RickJames I'm afraid that if I do that, I might lose some data because I know that at least some of the tables contain content in other languages such as Japanese. So also, tadman is correct in assuming that the source is UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: @Voidling - Japanese can be encoded in either UTF-8 or UTF-16.  For interchange (between products, etc), the computing world is moving toward UTF-8 for all situations.

Comment: I'm now trying to dump these tables to a .csv file but get errors saying it cannot to a destination data type "DT_IMAGE", which isn't specified in the export options. I explicitly configured it to export to "DT_TEXT". The column also doesn't contain any images to begin with. Is this a known problem for someone?